# how to set auto width of image in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I have this code in uploading image then displays the image with the resized one.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Image preview example</title>

</head>

<body onload="loadImageFile();">
  <form name="uploadForm">
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><img id="originalImg"/></td>
          <td><img id="uploadPreview"/></td>
          <td><input id="uploadImage" type="file" name="myPhoto" onchange="loadImageFile();" /></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </form>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
oFReader = new FileReader(), rFilter = /^(?:image\/bmp|image\/cis\-cod|image\/gif|image\/ief|image\/jpeg|image\/jpeg|image\/jpeg|image\/pipeg|image\/png|image\/svg\+xml|image\/tiff|image\/x\-cmu\-raster|image\/x\-cmx|image\/x\-icon|image\/x\-portable\-anymap|image\/x\-portable\-bitmap|image\/x\-portable\-graymap|image\/x\-portable\-pixmap|image\/x\-rgb|image\/x\-xbitmap|image\/x\-xpixmap|image\/x\-xwindowdump)$/i;

oFReader.onload = function (oFREvent) {

  var img=new Image();
  img.onload=function(){
      document.getElementById("originalImg").src=img.src;
      var canvas=document.createElement("canvas");
      var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
      canvas.width=img.width/2;
      canvas.height= img.height/2;
      ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,img.width,img.height,0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
      document.getElementById("uploadPreview").src = canvas.toDataURL();
      alert(canvas.toDataURL());
  }
  img.src=oFREvent.target.result;
};

function loadImageFile() {
  if (document.getElementById("uploadImage").files.length === 0) { return; }
  var oFile = document.getElementById("uploadImage").files[0];
  if (!rFilter.test(oFile.type)) { alert("You must select a valid image file!"); return; }
  oFReader.readAsDataURL(oFile);
}
</script>
</html>
```

now in this line :

```
canvas.width=img.width/2;
canvas.height= img.height/2;
```

sets the canvas/resized image with img width divide by 2 to get the half of the value.

my question is that how can I set this with static value of `width` and the `height` will get the `auto` resized value?

I tried like this but it didn't work.

```
canvas.width=500;
canvas.height='auto';
```

Comment: What is the end result you are going for? The HTML width and height attributes indeed don't support the `auto` keyword, only CSS does.

Comment: hmm like I am going to get the height value of integer based on 500 width of the uploaded image

Comment: When you say you want to get the height based on the width, do you mean that you no longer want to preserve the aspect ratio (height based on previous height)? Do you mean that you want to stretch the image into a square?

Comment: my mistake.. it would be like this.. if the original size of the image is 1000x800.. then in the code in the resized image it will only ask of the width value like for example 500 then the height will auto to set into 400.. is it possible?

Comment: thanks kaiido.. it works :)

Comment: @gadss sorry wrote a wrong formula that will work only for some images formats. Look at the answer, may fit more situations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to calculate the ratio of your actual image, then you can use some easy calculation like this :

```
var ratio = img.height/img.width;
canvas.width = wantedWidth;
canvas.height = ratio*wantedWidth;
```

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
      var wantedWidth = +wWidth.value;
      img.onload = function() {
        var ratio = img.height/img.width;
        canvas.width = wantedWidth;
        canvas.height = ratio*wantedWidth;
        canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      }
      img.src = 'http://lorempixel.com/' + oWidth.value + '/' + oHeight.value;
    }, false);
```

```html
original width :
<input type="number" id="oWidth" value="200" /><br>
original height :
<input type="number" id="oHeight" value="400" /><br>
wanted width :
<input type="number" id="wWidth" value="300" /><br>
<button>Set it</button><br>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<img id="img" src="" />
```